# Whats wrong with this prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a prepared statement just learned few hours ago but i get always as return 0

```
$ip = $data 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT counter_ip 
                            FROM counter_out 
                           WHERE counter_ip = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip);
$stmt->execute;
$stmt->bind_result($r_ip); 
$stmt->fetch();
echo "<pre>";
echo $r_ip;
echo "</pre>";
```

bind_result i tried all i d b s,
But when i do it this way without prepared statement it works

```
$sql = "SELECT counter_ip 
              FROM counter_out 
             WHERE counter_ip = '$ip'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$dupecheck = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "<pre>";
echo $dupecheck[counter_ip];
echo "</pre>";
```

Do i have an error in the prepared statement?

Comment: I'm guessing `$stmt->execute;` is a typo? Should be `$stmt->execute();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt->execute;
```

This is a method. It should be:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: lol, damn, and i was trying a half hour to fix it...thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT counter_ip FROM counter_out WHERE counter_ip = :s");
```

Comment: well you're doing a $stmt->bind_param('s', $ip);
so you need to set a param first..